# Android - handling the back button

Tags: android

I have an app which requires the user to be logged in.  In the app, to be logged in is to contain a specific string in the SharedPreferences file.

It is totally working except for one use case: when the user presses the phone's back button.

Is there something different that happens in loading the page when the user presses the phone's back button that I should be aware of and account for in the code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are they pressing the back button from and where are you checking if they are logged in (for instance, the best are you confirming their authentication in onResume())?

Comment: @Sam If they are not signed in, I send them to the login screen. If from the login screen they press back, they end up on the original screen which no longer redirects them to the login screen for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        //do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

try the above code to handle back key event

Comment: @Agrawal thanks - where should this code be? On the page from which they press back? Or on the page where they end up after they press back?  Should it be called somewhere as the page loads?

Comment: the page which appear before you press back button

Comment: Is there any reason to use this method over `onBackPressed()` for Android 2.0 and later? Do you know if one, theoretically, faster?